# Hypernym for something like a blanket/sheet to cover oneself for keeping warm

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

- *Blanket* seems too specific, one can cover oneself with a thin sheet instead.
- *Bedsheet* somehow seems like what you'd sleep on, not what you'd sleep under.
- *Sheet* is too general. One has sheets of paper, plastic sheets, and so on.

Is there any word or concise phrase for this? It should relate specifically to bedding, and should include any typically-rectangular object made of cloth/fabric-like material, with which one covers oneself while sleeping or lying down. It should not include other kinds of covers, such as a cover for a book, or something kept on a utensil to cover it.
It should not include a bedsheet on which one sleeps either.

(Aside: Marathi has a word for this, पांघरूण.)

Comment: perhaps a covering?

Comment: That sounds too general again, it could be a covering of anything for any purpose.

Comment: AmE here. *Cover* is perfectly suitable. It includes anything from a thin sheet to a down comforter. If you want something *more* inclusive, *cover* is good, too. If you want something that connotes bedding only, I'd go with *cover*. It's not like people cover themselves with tarps, towels or coats routinely to sleep indoors, and when they do, they usually point that out.

Comment: @Susan In Malaysia and other parts of Asia, people use a cross between a towel and a blanket to put over themselves. They are very cheap and washable, and hence dispense with the need for sheets. It is so hot at night out there that you don't need much for warmth. We have a number which we have brought back and have used for years in Britain (if it is really hot in summer), for ourselves and the children.

Comment: Then I assume *cover* is an appropriate appellation for them. Sheets are also washable, btw. Also, we use similar coverings in the hospital. We call them "blankets" to differentiate them from "sheets", both of which we go through at an alarming rate in my Emergency Department. But I have often asked a nurse to give pt. x another "cover", which always results in their bringing them the blanket. Finally, I wasn't denigrating anyone. I've slept under worse on medical trips to Africa.

Comment: @Susan, you should put that as an answer—I agree that it is the best option available.

Comment: @Susan I don’t have a convert-comment-to-answer button. Well, I do, but then you don’t get the reps — and you should.

Comment: Well, 'cover' would include lots of things apart from bedding, such as album covers, book covers, and so on.

Comment: How about bedding?

Comment: 'bedding' probably includes things one sleeps on, and maybe even pillows. (I'm almost feeling guilty for nitpicking now...)

Comment: According to M-W, [*bedding*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bedding): the sheets and blankets that are used on a bed.

Comment: Terms vary and become conventionalized hither and yon. _Covering_ or _bedding_ is about the best one can do. More limited terms like _coverlet_ or _cover_ too often mean quite different things elsewhere. For instance, on my recent visit to Jaipur, I was shown things as "sheets" that I would have called "bedcovers" in the USA, and the things that were called "bed covers" were what I would have called "duvet covers". Etc.

Comment: @Prateek, so many words have differing meanings. That's what context is for. If the context clearly indicates something that is used to put over a person, nobody would misunderstand _cover_. If you disqualify that because it happens to also mean other things, then the answer is ***no***, there is no such word.

Comment: In various parts of the United States where I've lived—but especially in Texas—the generic colloquial term for sheets, blankets, quilts, etc., is "the covers." This term applies only to the various layers of bedding that people sleep under (and in winter pull up to their chins), so it is less generic than (for example) "coverings" would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure from your question whether you would include those items that go between the bed and the person, though I suspect not.

If you would include them, then *bedclothes* matches well.

If you would exclude them, then your closest match would likely be *bedcover* also found as hyphenated or open compounds (*bed-cover*, *bed cover*).

It is specifically for a bed, but general as to the material.

It is though *sometimes* taken to include the coverings between the bed and person, but often taken as only the top layer.

Amusingly, while checking to confirm that I was correct in saying it can be used to refer only to those items that go above the person, I found that in Webster's dictionary while he defined *bed* and *bed-clothes* he had not defined *bed cover* though he did use it in defining *rug*, and the OED in turn cites that use. It's not unusual the see one dictionary consider a compound worth defining while another does not, but it's mildly amusing to see the first case cite the second case as a usage.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few words that could be used, depending on your intended meaning: quilt, eiderdown, bedcover, duvet, bedspread, coverlet... All of these relate specifically to bedding. Not sure what your quoted word means exactly, but if you can define it, we might be able to come up with a suitable equivalent.

Comment: @Leon Conrad - this is not an answer to the OP's question. You made no attempt at an answer, just listing coverings. This is a comment, and belongs in comments.

Answer (score 0):

A possible hypernym that can include covers thrown over something and used to cover oneself is a **throw**. The definition below makes a distinction between a *throw* and *bedclothes*; as bedclothes can include covers like *bedsheets* which are not used to cover your body. On the other hand, the word *throw* is normally not used for bigger beddings like duvets, quilts etc.; thus there isn't a perfect unambiguous hypernym that includes covers/beddings that can only be used to cover oneself.

> **throw** (*n*) bedclothes consisting of a lightweight cloth covering (an afghan or bedspread) that is casually thrown over something 
> [*vocabulary.com*](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/throw)

> A large decorative piece of material or blanket used as a loose covering for furniture, or as a rug, bedspread, etc.; a piece of material draped over something. - *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/201411?rskey=fFtqRV&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)*

The term *throw blanket* can be used for smaller blankets. A *throw* can be a cover used for decorative purposes as well; however, you can still use them to cover yourself.

The word *throw* might be used for a rug too but it depends on the context; and usually used as a *throw rug*.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't call a sheet or a duvet a *throw*; I'd use it only for a smaller blanket put over the other bed clothes. I'd also use it for such a blanket put over a sofa or armchair.

Answer (score -2):

It is usually called a Topsheet

Comment: Generally good answers are expected to give sources. Could you provide a linked reference or dictionary entry?

Comment: In support of @SConroy's comment, you do need to provide more detail, as the system has flagged your answer for potential deletion for being too short. On this site, an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can add information using the [edit] link. For more guidance, see [answer]. I can also recommend taking the **[Tour]** :-)